# What is the Windows 7 alternative to Vista's 'Reliability and Performance Monitor' to monitor network traffic

Tags: performance, networking, windows-7, windows-vista, monitoring

Yesterday I was using my old Vista laptop and noticed it was rather easy to view which processes were using the network and how many bytes were send and received. Now when I open perfmon on Windows 7 it seems to be lacking this functionality.

I am aware that I can use netstat and tcpview to archieve this to some extend, but it doesn't have the nice overview of bytes sent/received/total. What is the best way to get a similar output out of Windows 7, preferably without outside tools?

Additional information: I am using Vista Enterprise and Windows 7 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just called 'Resource Monitor' in Win7 now.  You can find it by just typing 'resource monitor' in the start menu.

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I was looking for!